# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS] installing APK on Android Emulator

Tags: android, facebook

I got a new error btw. Therefore I changed the title of this question.

**old error**

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

has been solved by re-downloading the zipfile from the website and choose the location to be

> Android/sdk/platform-tools

which is where the executable adk is located. 
* The facebook developer website doesn't say where the file should be stored at, it could be anywhere I guess. But somehow I got the problem so I moved the file to platform-tools.

However, I got a **new error** which is

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

which results from the ABI of the emulator I run (Nexus 4API 22,CPU/ABI x86) doesn't match facebook APK I guess??
How'd I know which ABI of which emulator to use to solve this no matching ABI error?

I'm a total newbie in mobile app development. Android is my first environment I try because I know Java from school. So, I'm really sorry if what I asked is really obvious.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall the app from emulator first. It should fis your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer GmloMalo! I'm not sure which app you're talking about though. You mean the app I'm developing or the facebook app I try to install? If the latter, then I haven't succeeded in installing it yet. lol

I tried, however, re-downloading the APK though. Now I got a new error. You can read above, I've changed the title and everything.

Comment: This error could occur for another reason, even when app is not present on emulator.